# How to prevent XSS when inserting untrusted data into a textarea?

Tags: web-application, xss, filtering

I want to prevent XSS in my demo chat application (written in PHP) that I've created for blog posts. The chat insert messages into a textarea. The problem is that it's vulnerable to XSS. Somone can write `</textarea><script>alert('x');</script>`. To prevent this I can write:

```
preg_replace("%</(text)(area)>%i", "</\\1&#8203;\\2>", $message);
```

It split textarea with zero width space.

Is this enough to prevent XSS for this one case of textarea messages? Can you encode textarea in a different way like `<script` tag that will bypass this filter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not enough. One possible bypass:

```
</textarea ><script>alert(1)</script>
```

This works because of the extra space after `textarea`.

You could adapt your filter to catch this as well. But I wouldn't recommend it because the approach is already flawed.

If you do not need to allow a user-supplied subset of HTML to be rendered (which isn't the case here), then the proper protection against XSS in a HTML context is HTML-encoding:

```
$message = htmlentities($message, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo "<textarea>$message</textarea>";
```

Now the message will be displayed as intended, but there is no possibility for XSS.

Comment: The problem with this is that if someone will chat about html (for instance webmaster chat) and paste the snippet he is working on that have textarea it will show html entities insitead of html (which will look like chat is broken), I want to show html but I want it to be text inside textarea, this is not standard XSS, people usually don't use textarea. And textarea is special because only </textarea> have special html meaning everything else is just text. I don't care about any normal XSS. I want to just be bullet proof for this one case.

Comment: @jcubic No, it won't. It will return HTML entities in the HTML source, which will be rendered by the browser. Take a look at this answer for example. It displays the string `<textarea>$message</textarea>` just fine, and it uses HTML-encoding (the source contains `&lt;textarea&gt;$message&lt;/textarea&gt;`). If you want proper protection against XSS + usability (display string as-is, without rendering of HTML tags), HTML-encoding really is the way to go here.

Comment: Hm, didn't know that, it's simplify things, because I can use same XSS prevention for textarea and any other use case, like when reader will create his own chat without textarea. Thanks.